# How to get captions to display with zurbs foundation's orbit slider?

Tags: javascript, slider, zurb-foundation, captions, orbit

I have been stuck trying to figure this problem out. Any suggestions/fixes will be much appreciated!

The source:  [my source](http://gorillagency.com/orbit-test/)

**The problem:** The captions are not displaying

The html (for the orbit slider slides):

```
<div><img class="art-work" src="art/2.png" alt="" data-caption="#htmlCaption1" /></div>
<div><img class="art-work" src="art/3.png" alt="" data-caption="#htmlCaption2" /></div>
<div><img class="art-work" src="art/4.png" alt="" data-caption="#htmlCaption3" /></div>
```

....and so on

The html (for the orbit slider captions):

```
<span class="orbit-caption" id="htmlCaption1">Art #1</span>
<span class="orbit-caption" id="htmlCaption2">Art #2</span>
<span class="orbit-caption" id="htmlCaption3">Art #3</span>
```

...and so on

The js in html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
        $('#featured').orbit({
            bullets: true,
            timer: false,
            captions: true,
            animation: 'fade' 
        });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because you have the 'data-caption' attribute in the 'img' tag rather than the 'div' that wraps it. Change it to the following and it should work

```
<div data-caption="#htmlCaption1"><img class="art-work" src="art/2.png" alt="" /></div>
```